# Could "eternal" dictator be clueless in foreign policy theory?

Tags: internal-consistency, geopolitics

I'm writing a story about foreign policy student who needs to do an internship in his final year. And while his peers apply at think-tanks and government agencies, he has low grades and no connections. Destiny interferes and he manages to get an internship in a government of fictional MENA dictator who is more than 3 decades in power and managed to play different great powers against each other and stay independent.

His country is located on an important strait, through which large percentage of world trade passes through.

Is it possible for such person to operate just on instinct, without knowing anything about the international relations theory?

The meat of my story is comparing the student who knows things by the book. And the dictator who experienced all those things on his skin. Theorist vs practitioner.

Comment: Does "such person" refer to the dictator? How is the intern related (to the question)?

Comment: @RickM. Yes the dictator. The meat of my story is comparing the student who knows things by the book. And the dictator who experienced all those things on his skin. Theorist vs practicioner

Comment: I didn't even know that there "foreign policy theory" was a thing. (Of course, I know that there are institutions of higher learning which offer such courses, but I've always thought that their relationship with actual foreign policy was similar to the relationship between literary criticism and actually writing a successful novel.) Could you please quote the authors and titles of the most important treatises on this subject? Can you give real life examples, such as what studies in foreign policy theory did Stalin or Brezhnev have?

Comment: @AlexP Good point I will just assume that everyone works on instinct

Comment: The act of playing "different great powers against each other" will require good knowledge and skill to predict their actions. I would think that is the basis of foreign policy.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding,zurofo! If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. You may also find [meta] and [The Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) 
useful. Have fun!

Comment: @zurofo as a warning, there's a strong rule against questions concerning the actions of a single person.  Your question tends towards that.  Changing the question so that it talks about groups of people should avoid that little problem.  I think the central idea of your question is a good one.  It may need to just be tweaked a bit.

Comment: @zurofo Once you hit 20 rep points, come visit us in the chat. There are people who really enjoy this subject, so it could be a fun conversation. Might also be able to help you with wording on this question. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor

Comment: A given person may or may not be Machiavellian enough to survive on instinct in a given political situation while another may well make it with "room to spare" so to speak. This is not a question that has any generally applicable answer but rather the answer(s) will depend on the story you want to tell and the characters portrayed therein.

Answer (score 11):

### In theory, practice and theory are the same thing.

In practice, they're totally different.

It's important to not confuse book learning with actual skill.  If this hapless intern of yours is actually a really cunning negotiator and has excellent fingertip feel for political opportunities then he'll likely do well in a dictatorship.  Those two skills can't be taught in school and even if they could, the skills would be bound up in academic theory.

This applies to the dictator too.  In professions with long apprenticeships, it's impossible to write down everything there is to know.  It can only be learned by experience.  This dictator may have learned his skill from experience.  Even if he wanted to, he may not be able to convey what he knows.  Just because information can't be spoken or written, doesn't make it less real or less valuable.  In many cases, it is far more valuable than mere book learning.

Might I recommend the [Gervais Principle](https://www.ribbonfarm.com/the-gervais-principle/) for an incredibly interesting read on the power dynamics in organizations.

Answer (score 4):

He has control of something very valuable. If nobody is willing or able to take it from him by force he can blunder all he wants for a long time and people will call it clever because insulting powerful people is exactly what diplomacy isn't.

A person with a reputation for winning (as one might expect from a dictator who isn't dead yet) can afford to make silly moves sometimes simply because other people worry that it might be some sort of trap.

A lot of foreign relations are simpler for a dictator than a scientist, since the dictator can use the final argument of kings to prove their theories, can run direct experiments, and gets inside access to the true preferences and motivations of an important actor.

Foreign policy theory is more or less academics watching players, and then guessing why things (didn't) work. They come up with some very well thought through ideas and learn their history very well, but there is very little experimentation, and no controlled repeatability.

Answer (score 3):

Of course. Plenty of "great dictators" were and are idiots.

And him "playing the other powers" might mean "the great powers playing each other" combined with some blind luck and decent social skills.

He just needs aides who can hash out any details, and what is a dictator without his own Penultimo?

Comment: Historian Shelby Foote, while speaking during Ken Burn's *The Civil War* described one of the southern generals as brilliant though he had no formal training.  He would give commands that sound idiotic to the trained ear, but that translated to very practical and useful military tactics and procedures (for the day).  That general was a good example of what you're talking about - and for the life of me, I can't remember his name.

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Lots of jobs can be learned "on the job" through mentoring and trial and error.
Might even be pretty good at it if they are an intuitive person who's good at reading people.
That's not really something they can teach in school, but it's pretty important to know for successful international relations.

The schooling might help some people, but there will still be things to learn afterward just because you're dealing with real people, not theory.

Answer (score 1):

If the dictator has been ruling his country for more than 30 years  without losing his sovereignty, it shows they have done a good job(Keeping other great powers from overturning his dictatorship and losing control over the strait). With time the experience they gained over time would shape to form the theory gained by the intern. In fact theory is based on  the experience gained by other people in the field. So I think there would not be much of conflict between the two .

Comment: Downvoted because the answer really needs to expand on what is meant by "good job".  Certainly it's not difficult to point to dictators, or dynasties of dictators, who held power for decades without doing anything that I would consider as good.  Mugabe in Zimbabwe, the Kims in North Korea, the Castros in Cuba...

Answer (score 1):

Often times, in strategic pursuits(such as international political theory), strategy gets "exalted" to a "school of thought".  While such strategies were incredibly valid within the limited confines of their targeted contexts, they are of only limited success as a school of thought, producing blindspots, and rejecting valid strategies that run counter to the exalted one.

This is an issue that's more prevalent in Academia than it is in the school of Hard-Knocks because the former's *GOAL* is to find and codify a legitimate School of Thought to work with.  At least among the elites of the two institutions.

Having your Dictator constantly correct the student with "Context is everything" or "Ah, usually, that is true, but I happen to know that....".  These sorts of corrections keep the student's previous studies as "valid", but reduce their broad applicability.